# Get selected value when using listgroup.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and  listgroup.js (https://github.com/rickardn/listgroup.js) to turn a select dropdown visually into a list. However, as soon as I add class="list-group" to the select, my javascript is no longer able to get the selected value.

HTML

```
<select id="selecteduser" name="selecteduser" class="list-group">
    <option value="user1">user1</option>
    <option value="user2">user2</option>
    <option value="user3">user3</option>    
</select>
```

JS

```
$("#selecteduser").change(

function() {
//get the selected value
var selectedValue = this.value;

//make the ajax call
alert("You selected " + selectedValue);
}

);
```

The listgroup.js makes reference to the actual select being hidden, but how can I get the selected value from this hidden select in my Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to list-group.js plugin [documentation](http://rickardn.github.io/listgroup.js/#select-elements) the javascript API not implemented yet:

> More to come Because this project just got off the ground not
>   everything have been documented fully. Examples of functions that
>   exist but which will be described here incrementally are
>
> The JavaScript API

But here is quick workaround

```
$(".list-group > a").on('click', function() {

    alert("You selected " + $(this).data('value'));

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8tbsktq/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is weird, because it obviously works on jsfiddle but it's not working in my environment :/

Comment: Can you share a whole page where this code is not working?

Comment: I have ended up not using listgroup.js.

I used a normal bootstrap 3 list-group, with link elements, and an onClick event with parameters to trigger my javascript and let it know what was clicked on.